# WSGIServer backend with React - Handling long running script

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, wsgi

My Python WSGI server calls a separate python script that can take ~5 minutes to process. What is the best way for me to handle this? At the moment, the web browser waits and returns once the script is successful.

I'm having trouble finding examples of how to accept the request, run a long script, and then tell React 5 minutes later, "hey it's done!" - instead of having chrome stalled in a loading state.

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rq` or `celery` as Worker Instance. `rq` is pretty simple and minimal where `celery` is full-featured but a bit overwhelming  Here is how it will work.

```
def execute_background_task(param):
          your task...
def request(param):
        execute(param)
        return "Your Request is getting processed"
```

So `execute_background_task` will be executed by rq or celery in the background. And from the frontend you send request to sever than 'Hey rq/celery, did you finish the task?'. So how do you get to know did they finish it or not?

**Solution:** You will get a Job ID of each task that is getting executed in background. You can query with that , if it finished or not.

I think you should check some wonderful documentation to do play with it. Here are some cool links that i followed:

https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/

https://flask-rq2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/